# asp.net MVC Base Controller error - Type Expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Using VS 2010 and the latest version of ReSharper...

When I create a BaseController class I get the red squiggly stating the "Type is Expected". The project will still compile but I have not tried to run it yet.

See attached image.

Any ideas what causes this?

[image]

Comment: Try closing and reopening the file.

Comment: Thanks... that fixed it. Post as an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Close and reopen the file.

Comment: I just apply this and it works like a charm !! (nice bug microsoft)